# Maximize pixels - Android Browserd Address Bar

Tags: android, browser, pixel

How big, in pixels is the Android web-browsers addressbar? (not counting the status bar).

I can't seem to find any information on this at all.

UPDATE

I'm mentioning the standard browser that ship with the Nexus. And there should be three sizes (four counting xdpi). Do anyone know the pixel size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will vary by Android version, by screen size/density, and by browser (standard, manufacturer-modified, third-party like Mozilla). Hence, there is no single answer.

Comment: @Joakim Engstrom: Please read http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/best-practices.html. You will notice that nowhere in there do they discuss the address bar. Please follow their recommendations for designing your Web site. Do not make any assumptions regarding the address bar, which may or may not even be visible at any given point (usually it's not visible, unless the user is attempting to type into it). Also, there are multiple "Nexus" devices.

Comment: Even though I still would like to know the height of the pixels this is an acceptable answer since I should not be coding a webpage based on pixels when coding a website for mobile devices. But when a designer wants to know how many pixels the adressbar is in I thought it would be an easy answer on the Nexus:es (both is hdpi screens and should therofore be the same pixel size designwise). But thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: @Joakim Engstrom: "both is hdpi screens and should therofore be the same pixel size designwise" -- yes, they are both `hdpi`. That does not mean they will both have the same address bar height. They might, since they are both running Android 2.3 and are largely "Google Experience devices", so device manufacturers may not have messed around with them. I wish that the Android SDK Hierarchy Viewer worked with devices, as that would be the easiest way for you to get your height. As it is, I'd just take a screenshot using DDMS and measure it in your favorite image editor.

Answer (score 0):

This is device dependent (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)- look for information for accommodating different resolutions.

Comment: But I'm not building a native android application. I'm building a website.

Comment: But same answer - if you are trying to emulate the android web browser, it will vary from device to device

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate this yourself if you use the emulator and set up devices with various densities and no scaling.